# Creating a simple webpage with Python, where template content is populated from a database (or a pandas dataframe) based on query

Tags: python, django, pandas

I use python mainly for data analysis, so I'm pretty used to pandas. But apart from basic HTML, I've little experience with web development.

For work I want to make a very simple webpage that, based on the address/query, populates a template page with info from an SQL database (even if it has to be in a dataframe or CSV first that's fine for now). I've done searches but I just don't know the keywords to ask (hence sorry if this a duplicate or the title isn't as clear as it could be).

What I'm imagining (most simple example, excuse my lack of knowledge here!). Example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3], columns=["Header","Body"], data=[["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]])
Out[1]: 
  Header Body
1      a    b
2      c    d
3      e    f
```

User puts in page, referencing the index *2*:

```
"example.com/database.html?id=2" # Or whatever the syntax is.
```

Output-page: (Since id=2, takes data row data from index = 2, so "c" and "d")

```
<html><body>
Header<br>
c<p>
Body<br>
d<p>
</body></html>
```

It should be pretty simple right? But where do I start? Which Python library? I hear about Django and Flask, but are they overkill for this? Is there an example I could follow? And lastly, how does the syntax work for the webpage address?

Cheers!

PS: I realise I should probably just query the SQL database directly and cut out the pandas middle-man, just I'm more familiar with pandas hence the example above.

Edit: I  a word.

Comment: flask is much easier to do very simple things ... especially if you dont need user authentication or any of the bells and whistles django provides ... alot of times a project starts small with flask ... but before long you are implementing most of django

Comment: Using Jupyter isn't good enough for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with flask, It is easy to setup and lots of good resources online,
Start with this minimal web app http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/

Example snippet

```
@app.route('/database')
def database():
    id = request.args.get('id') #if key doesn't exist, returns None
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3], columns=["Header","Body"], data=[["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]])
    header = df[id].get("Header")
    body = df[id].get("Body")

    return '''<html><body>Header<br>{}<p>Body<br>d<p></body></html>'''.format(header, body)
```

For more detailed webpage add a template.
Good luck